# Expanding Date Ranges

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, recursive-query

I want to expand the date ranges in the below "Original Table". The end result should be the "Resultant Table". I know that this can be done in sql using dateadd and ctes. However, I cannot get the join right to get the result as shown below. Please suggest possible solutions.

[image]

The query I am using is something like this:

```
WITH Calendar AS  
(  
  select DATEADD(day, 1, '2019-08-01') as date
  UNION ALL  
  select DATEADD(day, 1, date) 
  from Calendar 
  where date <= '2019-08-05'  
)
SELECT o.Column1,o.Column2,o.Column3, calendar.date
FROM OriginalTable o
 inner join calendar
on calendar.date=o.Column3
```

The result it gives me is the original table. I have played around with various options and it gives me other incorrect results.

Comment: Outer join a help calendar table/cte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate problem with your query is that you should be using a `left join` rather than an `inner join` in the outer query, so "missing" dates are not filtered out.

However, this is probably not sufficient. You also need to keep track of the original values so you can put them in the newly generated rows.

It might be simpler to generate the rows directly from the recursive query:

```
with cte as (
    select column1, column2, column3, lead(column3) over(order by column3) lead_column3
    from original table
    union all
    select column1, column2, dateadd(day, 1, column3), lead_column3
    from cte
    where dateadd(day, 1, column3) < lead_column3
)
select * from cte
```

Comment: This is a fantastic, elegant solution (note: to be technically correct, "original table" should be "originaltable", and "select *" should be "select column1, column2, column3"), but be aware that there is a recursion limit in effect (which defaults to 100), so it only works if the largest gap between two dates is not greater than this limit. To see this, try changing the final row to be (b, z, '8/12/2021').

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the post by @GMB, there is a potential issue with a recursive solution (recursion depth is limited; 100 by default). In order to sidestep that, one alternative solution is to use a GENERATOR function instead (though the requires 2 steps, which might not be acceptable for the OP's use case).

```
SET RC = (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, COLUMN3, LEAD(COLUMN3) OVER (ORDER BY COLUMN3)) AS DAY_GAP FROM OriginalTable ORDER BY DAY_GAP DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 1)
;

WITH X1 AS (
  SELECT *
        ,LEAD(OT.COLUMN3) OVER (ORDER BY COLUMN3) AS COLUMN3_NEXT
    FROM OriginalTable OT
)
,X2 AS (
  SELECT SEQ8() AS DAY_OFFSET
    FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => $RC))
)
SELECT X1.COLUMN1
      ,X1.COLUMN2
      ,DATEADD(DAY, X2.DAY_OFFSET, X1.COLUMN3) AS COLUMN3
  FROM X1
       CROSS JOIN X2
 WHERE (DATEADD(DAY, X2.DAY_OFFSET, X1.COLUMN3) < X1.COLUMN3_NEXT OR X2.DAY_OFFSET = 0)
;
```

Comment: @GMB I did try different types of joins without success. Your solution is really simple and elegant.

Comment: haven't tried your solution yet. Will try it and revert. Thanks!